# Cannot run flutter project with cloud_firestore dependency

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I created a new project, with the default main page, and added a few dependencies to the pubspec.yaml file. I noticed that if I have cloud_firestore in the dependencies list my app won't run and I get a lot of errors. This issue started randomly, and I can't run any of my projects with cloud_firestore as a dependency.

I tried making a fresh new project, and only added the cloud_firestore dependency, and I still get the same error. I am just going to wipe my computer **(This solved the issue)**

**Output Error:**

> [macos/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/protobuf/examples] dart pub get
> Resolving dependencies...
> pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint.
> You should edit pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:
>
> environment:
> sdk: '^3.0.0'
>
> See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-constraint
> exit code 65

**Debug Error:**

> Xcode build done.                                            6.5s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
> /Applications/Development/boiler_betas/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/tsi/ssl/key_logging/ssl_key_logging.h:22:9
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

**pubspec.yaml file:**

```
name: boiler_betas
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.4
  image_picker: ^1.0.2
  video_player: ^2.7.0
  file_picker: ^5.3.3
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.3
  intl: ^0.18.1
  chewie: ^1.7.0
  http: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: how are you adding firestore? If you are hardcoding version in pubspecy.yaml and then running `flutter pub get`, then consider running `flutter pub add cloud_firestore`, let pub add a matching version by itself.

Comment: @Obum Thanks! I didn't know 'flutter pub add' was a command I could use. I will do that for the future

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you may have an outdated version of Flutter - have you tried upgrading? That should begin generating new projects with a sufficient SDK constraint.

However, for your existing projects, you can change these lines:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <4.0.0'
```

into this

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '^3.0.0'
```

Comment: I took the extreme route and rebooted my computer (which I was planning on doing away), then reinstalled everything, and it worked again. I feel like I did try upgrading Flutter before I wiped my computer, but maybe I didn't.  

And I did try changing my sdk constraint to '^3.0.0', but it then tells me I need to specify a lower constraint.

Comment: The need to specify a lower constraint is probably coming from a different dependency specifying a maximum SDK version of `2.*.*`.